# I keep getting a expected then error when I have the the in the string

Tags: computercraft

I keep getting the then expected error on line 61 and I cant find the problem any ideas?
I tried working it out and rearranging it im using computer craft periherals mag card reader and trying to mag a card door

```css
os.loadAPI("SHA")
os.pullEvent = os.pullEventRaw

redstone.setBundledOutput("left",colors.white)
math.randomseed(os.time())

term.clear()
term.setCursorPos(1,1)
print("DKM.inc Doors")
print("thank you")

modem = peripheral.wrap("top")

if moden == nil then
  error("Modem not on top")
end

if moden.isPresentRemote("mag card reader_0") then
  reader = peripheral.wrap("mag card reader_0")
  print("Card reader connected")
else
  error("Mag-card reader not found")
end

if modem.isPresentRemote("monitor_0") then
  monitor = peripheral.wrap("monitor_0")
  print("monitor connected")
else
  error("monitor not found")
end

hashedPw = "0706490"
cardsFilePath = "cards"
cards = {""}
chars = {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"}
newpass = ""
cardNum = 0

if fs.exists(cardsFilePath) then
  cardsFile = fs.open(cardsFilePath, "r")
  cards = textutils.unserialize(cardsFile.readAll())
  cardsFile.close()
end

while true do  
  admin = false
  
  monitor.clear()
  monitor.setCursorPos(1,1)
  monitor.write("Please insert card")
  reader.setInsertCardLight(true)
  
  
  event, p1,p2,p3 = os.pullEvent()
  
  if event == " mag_swipe" then
    if SHA.SHA1_2(p1) == hashePw then
      admin = true
    end
    for x = 1, #cards do
      if SHA,SHA1_2(p1) == cards[x] then --line 61 is right here
        reader.setInsertCardLight(false)
        redstone.setBundledOutput("left", 0)
        os.sleep(3)
        redstone.setBundledOutput("left", colors.white)
        reader.setInsertCardLight(true)
        break
      end
    end
  end
  if admin == true then
    reader.setInsertCardLight(false)
    monitor.clear()
    monitor.setCursorPos(1,1)
    monitor.write("Admin granted insert blank card")
    for z = 1,15 do
      case math.random(1,2)
      a = math.random(1,#chars)
      if case == 1 then
        x=string.upper(chars[a])
      elseif case == 2 then
        x=string.lower(chars[a])
      end
      newpass = newpass..x
    end
    reader.setInsertCardLight(true)
    cardNum = #cards
    print(reader.beginWrite(newpass, cardNum..""))
    table.insert(cards, SHA,SHA1_2(newpass))
  
    while reader.isWaiting() do
    end
  
    reader.setInsertCardLight(false)
    monitor.clear()
    monitor.setCursorPos(1,1)
    monitor.write("new card created")
    newpass = ""
  end

  os.sleep(1) 
 
  cardsFile = fs.open(cardsFilePath, "w")
  cardsFile.write(textutils.serialize(cards))
  cardsFile.close()

end
```

Comment: can you make a comment @ line 61 so that we can see where the error occurs? thx

Comment: I changed it where it has a comment at the end of the line

Comment: I think you have to replace SHA,SHA1_2 with SHA.SHA1_2 (the komata)

Comment: Thank you next time I get on my computer I'll try to fix it and see if it work because it 4AM

Answer (score 1):

You miss spelled "modem" with moden on 2 lines.

```
if moden == nil then
```

and also..

```
if moden.isPresentRemote("mag card reader_0") then
```

As for the error.

```
if SHA,SHA1_2(p1) == cards[x] then --line 61 is right here
```

i believe.. should be this..

```
if SHA.SHA1_2(p1) == cards[x] then --line 61 is right here
```

swapping the `,` for a `.` should do the trick.